# How do I access the login history and wake-up reason on macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos-sierra

Can someone tell me what code do I use to access login history (successful/failed login attempt & time) and wake-up reason (why the computer is waken from sleep) on Sierra?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Find wake reason:

```
log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Wake reason"'
```

Show login history:

```
last | grep -i ttys
```

If you're on a version that predates Sierra, the `log` command doesn't exist. Use the following instead:

```
syslog | grep -i "Wake reason"
```